# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (using signal function...)

Tags: python, django

ok, I know this means that my backend python code is wrong but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. because the error doesn't help much, I'm having hard time finding out what the problem is. if anyone can detect it, I would appreciate it.

What I'm trying to do, notify when comment is submitted.

```
new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
notify.send(request.user,recipient='poster', action='respondposter')//see this one? I'm connecting it with signal

hidden_data = {
    "post_id" : post.id,
    "origin_path" : request.get_full_path,
    "parent_id" : None
}
comment_form = CommentForm(hidden_data=hidden_data)
html = render_to_string('main/parent_comment.html', {'comment': new_comment, 
                        'user': request.user, 
                        'comment_form':comment_form})
response_data = {"status":200, "message":"new comment_stored", "comment":html, 'parent': False}
return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

in models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):

    # sender = 
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile, related_name='notification')
    action = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.action)

def new_notification(sender,recipient, action, *args, **kwargs):
    print recipient
    print action
    new_notification_create = Notification.objects.create(recipient=recipient, action=action)//I found out this line is causing the problem 
    print sender
    print args
    print kwargs

notify.connect(new_notification)
```

can someone see what I'm doing wrong?or is this too vague for you too?

Thanks to the comment, I got traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/comments/views.py" in comment_create_view
  82.               notify.send(request.user,recipient='poster', action='respondposter')
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  201.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/notifications/models.py" in new_notification
  20.   new_notification_create = Notification.objects.create(recipient=recipient, action=action)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  346.         obj = self.model(**kwargs)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  468.                 setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __set__
  635.                     self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /comment/create/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "'poster'": "Notification.recipient" must be a "MyProfile" instance.
Request information:
GET: No GET data
```

Edit:

```
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            response_dat = {"code":400,"message":"Post does not exists"}
            return JsonResponse(response_data)


        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                notify.send(request.user,recipient='parent_comment.user', action='respondtouser')
                hidden_data = {
                    "post_id" : post.id,
                    "origin_path" : request.get_full_path,
                    "parent_id" : parent_comment.id
                }
                comment_form = CommentForm(hidden_data=hidden_data)
                html = render_to_string('main/child_comment.html', {'comment': [new_comment], 
                                        'user': request.user, 
                                        'comment_form':comment_form})
                response_data = {"status":200, "message":"comment_stored", 
                                                "comment":html, 
                                                'parent': True, 
                                                'parent_id': parent_comment.id,
                                                'comment_count': parent_comment.comment_count()}
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                notify.send(request.user,recipient='Post.moderator', action='respondposter')

                hidden_data = {
                    "post_id" : post.id,
                    "origin_path" : request.get_full_path,
                    "parent_id" : None
                }
                comment_form = CommentForm(hidden_data=hidden_data)
                html = render_to_string('main/parent_comment.html', {'comment': new_comment, 
                                        'user': request.user, 
                                        'comment_form':comment_form})
                response_data = {"status":200, "message":"new comment_stored", "comment":html, 'parent': False}
                return JsonResponse(response_data)

        else:
            print str(form)
            messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
            response_data = {"status":400,"message":"There was an error with your comment."}
            return JsonResponse(response_data)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

I get parent_comment is not MyProfile, post.moderator is not MyProfile

Comment: Dont you have access to a log with a traceback?

Comment: @lapinkoira, thank you now I have traceback

Comment: Well, can you print type(recipient) to check that variable's type, it's obvious it's not a MyProfle

Comment: @lapinkoira <type 'str'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call `notity.send` with a string `"poster"` as recipient. But the `Notification` model expects a `MyProfile` Instance.

You should first get the recipient from the database.

```
recipient = MyProfile.objects.get(...)
notify.send(request.user, recipient=recipient, action='respondposter')
```

Comment: thanks but I already changed to post.moderator but this doesn't do the trick either

Comment: /i'll post the full code...if you can look at it I would be appreciated

Comment: What type has `post.moderator`? I assume its a `User` instance? But your model needs a `MyProfile` instance

Comment: no it should be MyProfile instance, I already checked if it's user instace but it gives me same error but replaced myprofile over User...

Comment: class Comment(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
 parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)

Comment: I have myprofile for this but it gives me no myprofile

Comment: You still call `notify.send` with a string! `recipient='parent_comment.user'` remove the `'` to pass the instance.

Comment: opps my mistake, but for post.moderator it still isn't working

Comment: change `'Post.moderator'` to `post.moderator`

Comment: because `post` is an instance of the `Post` model.

Comment: ok so whenever I have some model, say Apple with juice field in my models.py, I can do apple.juice in my views.py?

Comment: No. But you have this line: post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id). PS: You should defintely look at the django tutorial :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/